# Assigning existing display template to Drupal view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-theming

How can I assign an existing template file (template file of an another view) to Drupal view.
I already have a template `views-view--search-issue.tpl.php` for `search_issue` view. Is there any way to use the same template for another view `archive_issue`? Or is it necessary that I have to create a new template for that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you might want to implement some preprocess hook that lets you add some suggestions. Something like this (it's not tested and maybe you'll need a different hook but to get an idea):

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_views_view (&$vars) {

  $view = $vars['view'];
    if ($view->name == 'archive_issue') {
      $vars['template_files'] = 'views-view--search-issue';   
    }

}
```

But like Aniruddhsinh said, the easiest way is to just copy paste the code you need in the appropriate template. Maybe you're feeling that you're violating the DRY manta (Don't Repeat Yourself), but in this case it's better than to break the pattern for views templates. Just go with Aniruddhsinh solution.

Source: [Suggested template files for views](http://groups.drupal.org/node/18276)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your archive_issue view and select the template file name. Create a template file with the same name from archive_issue and copy the content from views-view--search-issue.tpl.php which is for your search_issue.Paste it into this archive's template file. Clear the cache because of template changes and you will get the same template as it is in search_issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of this method. I want to know if i can use the same template. Please let me know about if there is any chance for that.